# 405 Method not Allowed - JSON - The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a course in Udacity for developing web app with Python. At the moment, it was introduced JSON to handle request form. I've written already more than once the codes explained in the lesson, and I am 99% that I did write everything correctly. But I always get the error "405 method not allowed" when I try to use the request form. Searching online has get me nothing, I couldn't find a solution for my problem.
Following here the python route that it was supposed to run:

```
 @app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
 def create_todo():
    description = request.get_json()['description']
    todo = Todo(description=description)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({
        'description': todo.description
    })
```

And here the script in HTML

```
 <script>
            document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                fetch('/todos/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': document.getElementById('description').value
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }) 
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.json(); 
                })
                .then(function(jsonResponse){
                    console.log(jsonResponse);
                    const lil_item = document.createElement('LI'); 
                    lil_item.innerHTML = jsonResponse['description'];
                    document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(lil_item); 
                }); 
            }
        </script>
```

I hope somebody could help me, I really don't know how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Edit - Inserting full HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Todo App
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" >
            <input type="text" id="description" name="description" />
            <input type="submit" name="Create" />
        </form>
        <ul id="todos">
            {% for d in data %}
            <li>  {{d.description}}  </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                fetch('/todos/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': document.getElementById('description').value
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        
                    }
                }) 
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.json(); 
                })
                .then(function(jsonResponse){
                    console.log(jsonResponse);
                    const lil_item = document.createElement('LI'); 
                    lil_item.innerHTML = jsonResponse['description'];
                    document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(lil_item); 
                }); 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that space really there before the `@`?

Comment: No there isn't in the original code.

Comment: Can you paste the full HTML.

Comment: Yes, I edit the post with the full html

Comment: did you check if it even allow json data? because 405 means something wrong with input or type of request, but POST and url is correct

Comment: I have no idea how can I check it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html document, the form object doesn't have an id.
In the javascript code you are looking for the submit event on the object with the id = "form", but such element doesn't exist.

So you just have to change:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description" />
    <input type="submit" name="Create" />
</form>
```

and then in JS:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = ...
```